# django heroku, import error: no module named photos.apps

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

I'm new to the web development and especially server deployment, so have been reading, searching and working my way through.

However, I'm getting stuck on the deploying to the Heroku, I think I should have the correct procfile setting, which is as following (the mysite is the root folder for the project, and the app under that is called photos)

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi
```

I tried on my location machine, either one of the following can get me started;

```
python manager.py runserver
guricorn mysite.wsgi
```

But when I deploy it on to the Heroku, I got error message saying:

> ImportError: No module named photos.apps
>   2018-04-25T20:28:48.321352+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-04-25 20:28:48
>   +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10) 2018-04-25T20:28:48.346604+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-04-25 20:28:48
>   +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process

Given the same command can be ran locally to start up the server, I'm really not sure why the error message.

Hope someone can point me to the right direction.

edit following is the error log:
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 27, in setup
remote:            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
remote:            app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
remote:            module = import_module(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
remote:            **import**(name)
remote:        ImportError: No module named photos

Comment: Do you have any uncommitted changes? Heroku only sees what's in the Git commits you push.

Comment: One helpful command when using heroku is to run `heroku local` from a shell (rather than `runserver`) -- that will start your app using the heroku process, which may help in tracking down the error.

Comment: when I can heroku local, it has a warning sign saying no env file found,

Comment: but the I cannot access the localhost, so the app will not start, not sure not to track the errors.

Comment: actually, the local one was running fine, it was on a different port, but i can start up the server

Comment: @xiaolekong https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local has the instructions for setting up the .env file. Its used to setup any Config Vars that are setup inside of your heroku app and better helps to mirror your production environment

Comment: @TheRightChoyce Thanks, but I dont think the .env file is the issue, as I can run the server locally using: heroku local, which works fine. I also checked my file hierarchy; which should also be fine, the photo is my own app, I initially put 'photos.apps.Photosconfig', but after reading a lot of posts, I changed it to 'photos', but still doesnt work.

Comment: @xiaolekong, again, _do you have any uncommitted changes?_

Comment: I think, I find out why, when I clone my remote repo from heroku locally, somehow, the photo folder doesnt contain a file, but locally, I have all the files, and if I look at the git status, it says everything is up-to-date. any chance you know how to resolve that? @Chris

Comment: @xiaolekong, are you ignoring files in that folder (via `.gitignore` or similar)?

Comment: @Chris, I dont think so, its just so strange

Comment: What does `git check-ignore -v path/to/photo/file` give?

Comment: I think @Chris is on the right track here, sounds very likely to be a git issue. Double check to make sure you re-deployed to heroku using `git push heroku`. If you go to the "Activity" tab in your heroku project, you can see the last time your heroku app was updated.

Comment: @Chris thanks, i think i have solved that part of the issue, the problem is with the git side, now I got a different issue where it shows templatedoesnotexist, the template does exist, and I also checked my DIR:[]  and APP_DIRS:True settings are ticked. but it still cannot find the template... so much troubles for the first time.